# Create a cross-browser mixin for transform: rotate

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I want to create a mixin for sass that will apply a rotation to the specified element. The mixin should take one parameter, for the number of degrees of rotation to apply.

From css3please.com, I found a cross-browser way to implement this with CSS:

```
.box_rotate {
     -moz-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
       -o-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Saf3.1+, Chrome */
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* IE9 */
          transform: rotate(7.5deg);  
             filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(/* IE6–IE9  */
                     M11=0.9914448613738104, M12=-0.13052619222005157,M21=0.13052619222005157, M22=0.9914448613738104, sizingMethod='auto expand');
               zoom: 1;
}
```

This is all very easy to make a mixin for, except for the pesky IE matrix notation. Does anyone have any suggestions for a way to transform the degrees into the IE matrix transformation using sass, javascript, or a combo of both?

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I wrote the mixin, and it's hosted here: https://github.com/adambom/CSS3-Please-for-SASS

Comment: The biggest issue I know of with using IE's filter/Matrix Transform is that when a box is rotated, it is not rotated about the box's center.  Imagine rotating the box, drawing a rectangle minimally containing the rotated box, and then placing that container where the box originally was.  That produces an offset that none of these solutions (as of 10/31/2012) account for.  If that statement doesn't make sense, think of it this way:  If you rotated a box a the beginning of the html body using only the matrix in IE, the rotated box would be fully visible.  In other browsers, it'd be clipped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function allows to transform the degrees into IE matrix transformation.

```
//deg input defines the requested angle of rotation.
function degreeToIEMatrix(deg){   
    var deg2radians = Math.PI * 2 / 360;
    var rad = deg * deg2radians ;
    var costheta = Math.cos(rad);
    var sintheta = Math.sin(rad);

    var M11 = costheta;
    var M12 = -sintheta;
    var M21 = sintheta;
    var M22 = costheta;
}
```

You will find more informations [here](http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/element-rotation-ie-matrix-filter?blog=2).

Comment: To use implicit globals should not be encouraged.

Comment: Every variable definition in your function creates a global variable. You need to use `var` to create local variables.

Comment: I understand now why you said "implicit". thanks @adamse. More informations about scope http://rx4ajax-jscore.com/ecmacore/more/scope.html

Answer (score 21):

There you go:

SASS:

```
@mixin rotate( $degrees )
  -webkit-transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg)
  -moz-transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg)
  -ms-transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg)
  -o-transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg)
  transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg)

  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=#{cos($degrees)}, M12=-#{sin($degrees)}, M21=#{sin($degrees)}, M22=#{cos($degrees)})
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=#{cos($degrees)}, M12=-#{sin($degrees)}, M21=#{sin($degrees)}, M22=#{cos($degrees)})"
  zoom: 1
```

SCSS:

```
@mixin rotate( $degrees ) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg);
  transform: rotate(#{$degrees}deg);

  filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=#{cos($degrees)}, M12=-#{sin($degrees)}, M21=#{sin($degrees)}, M22=#{cos($degrees)});
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=#{cos($degrees)}, M12=-#{sin($degrees)}, M21=#{sin($degrees)}, M22=#{cos($degrees)})";
  zoom: 1;
 }
```

usage:

```
@include rotate( 24 )
```

or you could simply use compass and make your life a lot easier :P

Comment: It apperas the prefix declarations should be rotate(#{$degrees}deg); but thanks for the IE declaration :)

Comment: One other thing that should be noted, compass' sin and cos functions expect radians, not degrees, so prefixing with something like `$rad : $deg * pi() / 180;` and using `$rad`for the cos and sin functions works for me.

Answer (score 10):

The [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) is defined as

```
[[cos(A), -sin(A)],
 [sin(A),  cos(A)]]
```

where `A` is the angle. `M11` in the IE matrix is the first element of the first row; `M12`: the second element of the first row etc.

JavaScripts `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` operate on radians so you will have to turn your degrees into radians

```
radians = degrees * Math.PI / 180
```

Putting this together we get this function:

```
function rotationMatrix(degrees) {
  var A = degrees * Math.PI / 180;
  return [[Math.cos(A), -Math.sin(A)], [Math.sin(A),  Math.cos(A)]]
}
```

Example:

```
rotationMatrix(10) 
// => [[0.984807753012208, -0.17364817766693033], 
//     [0.17364817766693033, 0.984807753012208]]
```

Comment: Usually you mark the best answer to your question as your accepted answer. Not the first, however if you think @lbdremy's answer was the best!

Comment: I just needed the algorithm. I ended up writing this function in sass anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of @Remy's code suitable for use in the javascript console. Just paste it into your console, then try makeIErotate(270), and it'll spit out cross-browser styles ready to paste into your CSS file.

BEWARE: the anti-aliasing in IE is ugly unless you have a solid background colour- even then it can be pretty blurry. More [here](https://github.com/mathquill/mathquill/wiki/Transforms).

```
function makeIErotate(deg) {    
    var deg2radians = Math.PI * 2 / 360;
    var rad = deg * deg2radians ;
    var costheta = Math.cos(rad);
    var sintheta = Math.sin(rad);
    return "-moz-transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);\n\
            -o-transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);\n\
            -webkit-transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);\n\
            -ms-transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);\n\
            transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);\n\
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(\n\
                    M11=" + costheta + ",\n\
                    M12=" + -sintheta + ",\n\
                    M21=" + sintheta + ",\n\
                    M22=" + costheta + ", sizingMethod='auto expand');";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the mixin, you should use

```
@include rotate(24)
```

Comment: RobinH answer is correct. If you are using compass (and you should be)it is as simple as typing: .yourbox {@include rotate(-90deg);} Let compass do all the hard work and keep your code clean =)